# How to use link generator from javascript variable ,in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to use link generator with Javascript function.

```
{% for key in values %}
<a href="#" onClick="bookConfirm('{{key}}'); return false;">click!!</a>  
{%endfor %}

function bookConfirm(key) {
    if (confirm("Is it OK?")) {
    alert("OK!!");

    location.href = "{{ path('acme_member_bookLesson',{'scheKey':key})}}";
    } else {
    alert("cancel!");
    }
}
```

but it shows

'Variable "key" does not exist in AcmeMemberBundle:Default:show.html.twig at line 19'

How can I solve this problem? it is little bit complex to use Javascript and link generator.

Comment: What does *"key"* refer to ? Did you forget pass it as a parameter in your controller ? Or are you doing a `for` loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The second `key` is not in the loop, that means that it'll always have the value of the last loop. You output the value of `key` as an argument to the JavaScript function. The second `key` value is not the key value of the javascript function, but the key value in twig. Why that is and how to fix it can be read in my original answer:

Twig is a templating engine written in PHP. That means it runs on the server side and outputs the text on in the code. Then the code is send to the browser and the browsers parses and renders/executes the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code.

So it isn't possible to execute some twig code with JavaScript.

However, you can simply fix your code using the [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle). That bundle does exactly what it says, it can handle most of the Symfony routing features on the client-side in JavaScript.

Your code would become something like:

```
function bookConfirm(key) {
    if (confirm("Is it OK?")) {
        alert("OK!!");

        location.href = Routing.generate('acme_member_bookLesson', { key: key });
    } else {
        alert("cancel!");
    }
}
```

Read more about it in [their docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown)

Comment: I edited my first topics.I use this sentence in {% for %} loop.So 'key' should be change,but it always show the same....Can I have any way to slove this??